# How can I clear memory being used by a UICollectionView after changing the data source?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that has a few different data sources, each one is an array of UIViews. But I notice that when I change the data source and reload the collection view, the memory usage doesn't stay similar or even go down, it increases.

So my question is how can I clear that memory being used? I have tried setting the data source to an empty array and calling `collectionView.reloadData()`, but that still did not clear the memory.

Thanks!

Code i'm using:

```
var allThumbArrays = [
        templatesSection1Small,
        templatesSection2Small,
        templatesSection3Small
    ]


class sectionsMenuLabels {

    static func section1Button() -> UIButton {
        let myButton = UIButton()
        myButton.setTitle("One", for: .normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(colours.darkbg, for: .normal)
        myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return myButton
    }

    static func section2Button() -> UIButton {
        let myButton = UIButton()
        myButton.setTitle("Two", for: .normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(colours.darkbg, for: .normal)
        myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return myButton
    }

    static func section3Button() -> UIButton {
        let myButton = UIButton()
        myButton.setTitle("Three", for: .normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(colours.darkbg, for: .normal)
        myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return myButton
    }
}

let sectionMenuButtonsArray: [UIButton] = [
    sectionsMenuLabels.section1Button(),
    sectionsMenuLabels.section2Button(),
    sectionsMenuLabels.section3Button()
]


let tWidth = ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20) / 3) - 15
let tHeight = (tWidth / 9) * 16
let tCollectionWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20


static func templatesSection() -> UICollectionView {
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 60, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: tWidth, height: tHeight)
        let myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tCollectionWidth, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)

        return myCollectionView
    }


       static func sectionsMenuView() -> UICollectionView {
        let sectionsMenuLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        sectionsMenuLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        sectionsMenuLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        sectionsMenuLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 110, height: 25)

        sectionsMenuLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10

        let sectionsMenu = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (screenSizes.screenWidth - 20), height: 35), collectionViewLayout: sectionsMenuLayout)

        return sectionsMenu
    }


//View controller File

class TemplatesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    let sectionsMenuView = sectionsMenuView()
    let templatesSection = templatesSection()

    let currentSectionShownNumber = 0
    var thumbsToUse: [UIView] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //MARK: sections menu collection view
        sectionsMenuView.dataSource = self
        sectionsMenuView.delegate = self
        sectionsMenuView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        sectionsMenuView.register(sectionsMenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SectionsMenuCell")
        self.view.addSubview(sectionsMenuView)

        sectionsMenuView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sectionsMenuView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenSizes.screenWidth).isActive = true
        sectionsMenuView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        sectionsMenuView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        sectionsMenuView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true

        //MARK: templates section collection view
        templatesSection.dataSource = self
        templatesSection.delegate = self
        templatesSection.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        templatesSection.register(TemplateViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SectionCell")
        self.view.addSubview(templatesSection)

        templatesSection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        templatesSection.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        templatesSection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        templatesSection.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20).isActive = true

        templatesSection.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true


    }




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if collectionView == self.sectionsMenuView {

            return sectionMenuButtonsArray.count

        } else {

            return thumbsToUse.count
        }

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if collectionView == self.sectionsMenuView {

            let sectionsMenuCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SectionsMenuCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

            sectionsMenuCell.addSubview(sectionMenuButtonsArray[indexPath.row])

            return sectionsMenuCell


        } else {


            let section1Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)


            //thumbs array
            thumbsToUse = allThumbArrays[currentSectionShownNumber]

            //add subview
            let viewToAddToCell = (thumbsToUse[indexPath.row])

            sectionCell.addSubview(viewToAddToCell)

            return section1Cell

        }



    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView == self.sectionsMenuView {



            currentSectionShownNumber = indexPath.row

            thumbsToUse.removeAll()

            templatesSection.reloadData()


            thumbsToUse = allThumbArrays[currentSectionShownNumber]

            templatesSection.reloadData()



        } else {

            chosenTemplateNumber = indexPath.row

            chosenTemplate = thumbsToUse[chosenTemplateNumber]

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: are you using single array? Can you please update your question with your code so get better idea.

Comment: sure i will update now

Comment: Still some information Missing. Can you please explain what you exactly want to do? what is `currentSectionShownNumber` used for? what is `templatesSection`?

Comment: `if collectionView == self.sectionsMenuView {}` Are you using two `collectionView` in one viewController

Comment: `templatesSection` is the main collection view, and `sectionsMenuView` is a  of collection view buttons to change the data source for the main one.

Comment: share your code if possible. will fix it

Comment: ok cheers i'll add it in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193183/discussion-between-krunal-nagvadia-and-brontea).